# Installing kubuntu desktop led to broken packages in Ubuntu unity 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, apt, package-management, kubuntu

I used kubuntu ppa to install kubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu unity 16.04, the canonical one. It led to broken packages. As others have pointed out [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/693735/350021) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/434404/350021), they figured out how to install kubuntu-deskop anyway however, I am not inclined to use plasma anymore. So I am uninstalling it. I just unchecked the kubuntu ppa/backports/Ubuntu Xenial in Softwares & Updates > Other Software. And then `sudo apt-get remove kubuntu-desktop`. I later realized that this was not the best way to rid my system of the kubuntu system conflicting with my unity DE. Anyway I learnt this the hard way when I was trying to install unity tweak tools.

So basically I realized that I had not gotten rid of softwares installed by the ppa in a good way leading to broken packages. Now I do not notice this when installing other packages. Only when dealing with qt, unity etc. I face this issue. I tried installing all unity stuff hoping this will remove all the kubuntu related packages.

```
sudo apt-get install unity-*
```

I got this error:-

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-chromium-extension : Depends: webbrowser-app
 unity-scope-click : Depends: account-plugin-ubuntuone
                     Depends: pay-service but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: ubuntu-sdk-libs but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-click-autopilot : Depends: ubuntu-ui-toolkit-autopilot but it is not going to be installed
                               Depends: unity8-autopilot but it is not going to be installed
 unity-scope-home : Conflicts: unity-scope-deviantart
                    Conflicts: unity-scope-gallica
                    Conflicts: unity-scope-github
                    Conflicts: unity-scope-googlenews
                    Conflicts: unity-scope-openweathermap
                    Conflicts: unity-scope-soundcloud
                    Conflicts: unity-scope-yahoostock
 unity-scope-tool : Depends: unity8-common (= 8.12+16.04.20160401-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 unity-webapps-qml : Depends: qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin or
                              qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin-gles but it is not going to be installed
 unity-webapps-service : Depends: webapp-container
 unity8-private : Depends: pay-service but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: qtdeclarative5-gsettings1.0 but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
                  Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-5-0
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Elsewhere they advise to clean, auto-clean, upgrade,dist-upgrade,auto-remove etc. Tried all, but no result. Unity seems to be in conflict. interestingly when I try :-

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5
```

It runs into error:-

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pyqt5 : Depends: qtbase-abi-5-5-1
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Using `aptitude` also is futile. It just says i cannot resolve your problem and does nothing. Can someone help me figure out how to remove kubuntu and the other softwares properly and reinstall unity properly.

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt install -f` ? It's a general catch all for the 'broken packages' error

Comment: Yes i ran it. Still got the error.